# Lagging when push to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

There is a lag when I'm pushing to a new ViewController and I don't know why.

[image]

I'm making `isNavigationBarHidden = false` and `view.backgroundColor = .white` but no changes.

**CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell:**

```
protocol RecipesDidselectActionDelegate: class {
    func recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let navigationController = UINavigationController()

    weak var recipesDidselectActionDelegate: RecipesDidselectActionDelegate?

    let categories: [String] = [
        "Main course",
        "Beef",
        "Chicken",
        "Seafood",
        "Vegetarian",
        "Breakfast",
        "Side dish",
        "Drink",
        "Sauce",
        "Soup",
        "Snacks",
        "Dessert"
    ]

    let categoriesImages: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "maincourse")!,
        UIImage(named: "beef")!,
        UIImage(named: "chicken")!,
        UIImage(named: "seafood")!,
        UIImage(named: "vegetarian")!,
        UIImage(named: "breakfast")!,
        UIImage(named: "sidedish")!,
        UIImage(named: "drink")!,
        UIImage(named: "sauce")!,
        UIImage(named: "soup")!,
        UIImage(named: "snacks")!,
        UIImage(named: "dessert")!
    ]

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var categoriesNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let categoriesNameLabel = UILabel()
        categoriesNameLabel.text = "Categories"
        categoriesNameLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        categoriesNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
        categoriesNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        categoriesNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoriesNameLabel
    }()

    lazy var seeAllCategoriesButton: UIButton = {
        let seeAllCategoriesButton = UIButton()
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitle("See all", for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitleColor(.CustomGreen(), for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        seeAllCategoriesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
        return seeAllCategoriesButton
    }()

    @objc func test() {
        print("Test worked")
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoriesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell")
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    }

    func setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoriesNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            categoriesNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seeAllCategoriesButton.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            seeAllCategoriesButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            seeAllCategoriesButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCollectionViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seeAllCategoriesButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(categoriesNameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(seeAllCategoriesButton)
        containerView.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupCollectionViewConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints()
        setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints()
    }

}


extension CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell
        cell.categoriesImage.image = categoriesImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoryName.text = categories[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        recipesDidselectActionDelegate?.recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let w: CGFloat = self.frame.width * 0.4
        let h: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.size.height - 6.0
        return CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }

}
```

**HomeView:**

```
protocol HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate: class {
    func recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: IndexPath)
}


class HomeView: UIView {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    weak var homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate: HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate?

    let categories = ["italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food"]

    override init( frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
        foodTableView.delegate = self
        foodTableView.dataSource = self
        foodTableView.register(CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell")
        foodTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        foodTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        foodTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return foodTableView
    }()

    func setupFoodTableView() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            foodTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            foodTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            foodTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(foodTableView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        indicator.setupIndicatorView(self, containerColor: .white, indicatorColor: .customDarkGray())
        addSubview()
        setupFoodTableView()
        fetchData()
    }

    func fetchData() {
        AF.request("apilink.com").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }
            do {
                if let data = response.data {
                    self.recipes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Recipes.self, from: data)
                    self.recipesDetails = self.recipes?.recipes ?? []
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.foodTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            self.indicator.hideIndicatorView(self)
        }
    }

}

extension HomeView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return recipesDetails.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.recipesDidselectActionDelegate = self
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
            let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
            cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
            cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title

            if let readyInMin = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].readyInMinutes {
                cell.cookingTimeInfoLabel.text = "\(readyInMin) Minutes"
            }

            if let pricePerServing = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].pricePerServing {
                cell.priceInfoLabel.text = "$\(Int(pricePerServing))"
            }

            if let serving = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].servings {
                cell.servesInfoLabel.text = "\(serving)"
            }

            return cell
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 2 {
            return "Random recipes"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.textColor = .customDarkGray()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return 130
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            return 180
        } else {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }

    }

}

extension HomeView: RecipesDidselectActionDelegate{
    func recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: IndexPath) {
            homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate?.recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

**HomeViewController:**

```
    class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: SideMenuTableViewController())

    lazy var mainView: HomeView = {
        let view = HomeView(frame: self.view.frame)
        view.homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate = self
        return view
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = mainView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavigation()
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        .lightContent
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        setupNavigationWithLargeTitle()
        setupLeftSideMenu()
    }

    func setupLeftSideMenu() {
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = leftMenuNavigationController
        leftMenuNavigationController.leftSide = true
        leftMenuNavigationController.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
        leftMenuNavigationController.presentationStyle = .viewSlideOut
        leftMenuNavigationController.allowPushOfSameClassTwice = false
        leftMenuNavigationController.menuWidth = view.frame.width * (3/4)
        leftMenuNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

}

extension HomeViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func setupNavigationWithLargeTitle() {

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.title = "Home"
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.CustomGreen()]
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.CustomGreen(), .font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Heavy", size: 36)!]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
    }

    @objc func saveButtonTapped() {
        print("OK")
    }

    @objc func menuButtonTapped() {
        self.present(leftMenuNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension HomeViewController: HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate{
    func recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Here you can push your destination View Controller
        let vc = RecipesTableViewDetails()
        self.show(vc, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to do some instruments to check what is causing the lag?

Comment: @AlexL.Rocha I tried but I didn't get why is that happening, It happened to me once before but was because I didn't put `backgroundColor` to the `view`, now I tried all I know but I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you double-check you are not doing fetchData() networking on the main thread.  Maybe try hardcode data and comment out the networking code to see if it helps.

Comment: @FaisalMemon I make it in the main thread but still the same problem, I don't think it's network problem. It's a UI problem.

Comment: You are not supposed to do networking on the main thread.  So that would need to be corrected.

Comment: @FaisalMemon I corrected it and still the same problem

Comment: Call to `super.loadView()` is allocating and assigning the `UIView` of the vanilla `UIViewController`. Try removing this call.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk Same problem.

Comment: show the code of show in `self.show(vc, sender:nil)`

Comment: @kjoe The full code: https://gist.github.com/Z1Z0/9a1fc7cf2fe2c00de035645da9b0ad9c

Comment: din't see the show code definition

Comment: a tip your view is doin to much, a MVC principle V does not knows about M, so network request does not belong to the view, that's business logic that belongs to controllers.

Comment: @kjoe Honestly I was going to fix it after fixing the current bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209339/discussion-between-kjoe-and-ahmed-abd-elaziz).